# Horizontal and vertical tangent space of Orthogonal group

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-spaces

We know for the orthogonal group n-by-n orthogonal matrices, the tangents are given by

$X^T\Delta + \Delta^TX = 0$ where $\Delta$ is the tangent.

Now I was reading about the vertical and horizontal spaces of the tangent space at some Q. This reference : Edelman et al.'s 1998 paper "The Geometry of Algorithms with Orthogonality Constraints" in section 2.3.1 says that

If we define the Stiefel manifold as a quotient space of the orthogonal group($O_n$) as

$[Q] = Q  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
I_p & 0 \\
0 & Q_{n-p}  \\ \end{array} \right) : Q_{n-p} \in O_{n-p}$

At a point Q, the vertical space is the set of vectors tangent to the set $[Q]$ and has the form

$\Phi = Q  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
0 & 0 \\
0 & C  \\ \end{array} \right)$ where C is any (n-p)-by-(n-p) skew symmetric matrix.

The horizontal space is defined as the tangent vectors at Q orthogonal to vertical space. It follows that the horizontal space at Q is the set of tangents of the form

$\Delta = Q  \left( \begin{array}{cc}
A & -B^T \\
B & 0  \\ \end{array} \right)$ where A is any p-by-p skew symmetric matrix.

I noticed that both $\Phi$ and $\Delta$ satisfy the condition for tangent vectors and that both are orthogonal (by the euclidean metric) but what I didn't understand was do they form a complementary subspace for the tangent space at Q. How can we prove that Dim(T(Q)) =  Dim($\Phi$) +  Dim($\Delta$). Also why do we consider this particular form of complementary spaces. Can't there be other forms of subspaces for the horizontal and vertical spaces?

Comment: T(Q) is a direct sum of the two sub-spaces since every skew symmetric matrix can be expressed as the sum of $\Phi$ and $\Delta$

Comment: Okay thanks Xipan but why that particular form. Why not something else which gives sum = skew symmetric matrix ??

Answer (score 0):

I'm reading this paper also. I don't have the correct answers to your questions, but I think my explanation below can give you some ideas about this problem.

Notice that the Stiefel manifold is the subspace of the Orthogonal group $O_n$ with dimension $n(n+1)/2$. Try to sum up the dimension of horizontal space and vertical space, we have
$$ dim(\Phi)+dim(\Delta) = dim(A) + dim(B) + dim(C)$$
$$ = \frac{p(p+1)}{2}+p(n-p)+\frac{(n-p)(n-p+1)}{2} = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}$$
I think we can inference that the tangent space at Q have same dimension as Orthogonal group $O_n$ (because there is no constraint on this space).
Sorry if I made some mistakes.